# How to select Country dropdown in Amazon site?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am learning selenium web driver and practicing Amazon site. I found a difficulty to automate the country selection in Amazon site.
Kindly help me what locators methods to be used to select the country on the pop up. 
[amazon URL.](https://www.amazon.com/)

Switch to Alert is not helping me..!

Answer (score 0):

- You can learn locators from these tutorials,

  1.[SeleniumEasy](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/selenium-locators)

  2.[ToolsQA](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/locators/)

  3.[Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html)

  4.[QTPSelenium](http://qtpselenium.com/)
- You can use Firefox browser add-ons like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/), [FireFinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/) and gradually you will be able to locate an element by writing Xpaths on your own.
- In Chrome browser, you can right-click on the desired web element and inspect. The HTML property belonging to that web element would be highlighted in the developer tool. Right click > Copy > Copy Xpath

Comment: I guess instead of using tools it would be better if we could program an xpath. Using firebug like tools or copy method won't necessarily give us a desired and reliable xpath or element locator.

Comment: Yes, I accept. But initially, we can use these for learning and then we will be able to write it on our own

Answer (score 0):

For the above scenario you could below xpath or css locator mentioned and then select the value you want to.

Xpath:

```
//a[@id='icp-touch-link-country']
```

CSS:

```
a#icp-touch-link-country
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below mentioned script and here I have used `"className"` locator for selecting the country on the popup.

```
       public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");

        //Scrolls down
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,5000)");
        //Clicks the country popup
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='United States']")).click();

        //Switches control to the new window
        Set<String> eachwin = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String win : eachwin) {

            driver.switchTo().window(win);

            //session id of the current window
            System.out.println(win);
        }

        //Selecting value from country dropdown
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.className("a-native-dropdown"));
        Select dropdown = new Select(ele);
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("India");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@class='a-button-input'])[2]")).click();

        //Switches to the new window with country selected
        Set<String> eachwin2 = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for(String win2 : eachwin2)
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(win2);

            //session id of the current window
            System.out.println(win2);
        }

    }
```